# Ruby: Split: Premature end of regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having problems using the split function in Ruby.
/Users/simonprochazka/Downloads/pes_test_p00/lib/main.rb:28: premature end of regular expression: /(/

```
 File.open(ARGV[0], "r") do |f|
   f.each_line do |line|
     data = line.split(/\t/)
     puts data[4]
     if data[4] =~ ["("]
     special = data[4].split(/(/)
     scores = special[0].split(/:/)
     puts data[4]
     else
     scores = data[4].split(/:/)
     end
     if special[1] != nil
     matches << Match.new(data[0], scores[0], scores[1], special[1].chop)
     else
     matches << Match.new(data[0], scores[0], scores[1])
     end
 end
 end
```

Comment: `irb(main):006:3>      special = data[4].split(/(/)`

Is this the problem line? I don't know what line is line 28 in your source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `(` character in regex, escape it: `/\(/`. Otherwise, it'll open a group. And unclosed group causes failure.

Answer (score 2):

Like said Nikita, `(` is a part of regex syntax, so this character have to be escaped by `\`.
Better use string instead of regex as parameter, when you want to split by only one character. Use `split('\\')`, `split(':')` etc.
Note, that string also have special characters and `\'` works as escaping of `'`, so you have to double it.